# Can I upgrade my MacBook Pro Mid 2010 to 8 or 16 GB RAM?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I was told that I could only upgrade to 4 GB. I read on your site that as of 2014 it’s possible to upgrade to 8 GB or 16 GB?

Is this true and how do I do this?

Specs: MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010) 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo equipped with 4 GB 1067 MHz DDR3.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean upgrading the RAM to 8 GB or 16 GB.

According to the following Apple support website, your MacBook Pro has a maximum RAM capacity of 8 GB:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201165

You would need to get two 4 GB modules with the correct specifications (PC3-8500 DDR3 1066 MHz type RAM) and replace them according to the steps described by Apple for your specific device.

Comment: According to [Everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.4-aluminum-13-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html) this model can support [16GB of RAM](http://radnex.us/PC3-8500-16GB-KIT) .

Comment: Apple’s official specifications often report a lower maximum RAM than is actually the case, and you should always cross-check them with third-party RAM vendors.

Answer (score -1):

MacSales is saying it can take (2) 8GB DIMMs for a total of 16GB. I'm trying to confirm this as well as I only have 4, and would love to go all the up to 16GB if possible.